# Can smartphone firmware be able to sniff outgoing HTTP requests of an Android phone?

Tags: android, networking, mobile, telecommunication

Can a mobile firmware app sniff all outgoing HTTP packets of a Wi-Fi network on a stock distribution device running Android OS connected to the fixed line (ADSL, for example).

In my understanding regarding what is stated here on [PCAP](http://www.kismetwireless.net/android-pcap/) page, for example, such is possible through custom firmware and by gaining root access. If so, could the firmware consist of something of a web proxy like [Transproxy](http://transproxy.sourceforge.net/)? I have doubts regarding the reliability of this approach because I know that there are apps that dont respect the central proxy settings (Firefox is one of them).

Or maybe the firmware could be implemented as an Android service that would act as hub for all outgoing HTTP traffic, by somehow forcing all the other apps to register to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS handles sending and receiving network data. Therefore the OS will also be able to look at the data if it wants to. I'm fairly sure this would have to be done at a system level, a service can't look at traffic from other apps.

Comment: I guess it is clear that I am not asking if a provider would add this, but if they could if they wanted. Can you elaborate more about some of those better ways to intercept data that you have mentioned?

Comment: What I meant was that if someone wanted your data, there are several points where it would be easier to intercept it. If the telecom provider wants the data you send over WiFi, it would have to intercept it on the phone, as this is the only device in the network they have control over. However, if you send the data over the mobile network, it would pass through their network, and it would be easier to capture it there.

Comment: I've also edited my question, so if you will, edit your question so I can mark it as an accepted answer :)